# linklist function not adding another list and causing infinite loop

Tags: c, function, linked-list

I was hoping to get some help with my add new node to a link list function I cannot seem to get it to link to create a new list.

```
void addNodeToList(tweet **tweetList, tweet *node)
{
    tweet *temp;
    temp = *tweetList;
    if (*tweetList == NULL)
    {
        *tweetList = node;
        return;
    } else
    {
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = node;

    }

    return;
}
```

This is my call for the function:

```
     if(menuOption==1){     
         tweets=createTweet( tweetList);
         addNodeToList(&tweetList,tweets);
         }
```

The Create Tweet Function is:

```
tweet* createTweet(tweet *tweetList)
{
    tweet *saveTweet = (tweet *)(malloc(sizeof(tweet)));
    int ascii[51];
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("Enter a username:\n");
    scanf("%s", saveTweet->user);

    printf("Enter the user's tweet:\n");

    scanf(" %[^\n]", saveTweet->text);

    while (saveTweet->user[i] != '\0')
    {
        ascii[i] = saveTweet->user[i];
        i++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
    {
        sum = sum + ascii[j];
    }
    sum = sum + strlen(saveTweet->user);
    saveTweet->id = sum;
    printf("Your generated user id is:%d\n", saveTweet->id);

    tweetList->next = saveTweet;
    return saveTweet;
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Im sorry hopefully it updated

Comment: It seems hard to properly indent code :/

Comment: Could you please include the entire `addNodeToList` function in your question? And include the `createTweet` function and the struct declaration as well...

Comment: That is the whole addtonode function that I have thus far

Comment: You should take the [tour], read [ask] and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Why does `createTweet` care whatsoever about `tweetList` That argument and the second-to-last line of this function seem both pointless and ultimately a recipe for orphaning whatever *used* to be chained to the head of the tweet list.  That function should just allocate a tweet, populate it, and return a pointer to it. Let the function that adds nodes to the list be the one to actually do the list placement.

Comment: thank you for helping

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes from your createTweet function, you are putting your new list at the end of your `tweetList` in createTweet function but you also do the same thing in addNodeToList, so you end up with a list pointing to itself like this:
member1->member2->member2->member2->member2...
Here's a better version of your createTweet function

```
tweet * createTweet( /*tweet * tweetList*/) {
    tweet * saveTweet = malloc(sizeof(tweet));
    int ascii[51];
    int i = 0; 
    int sum = 0;

    if (!saveTweet) // always check if malloc failed to avoid accessing wrong memory
        return (NULL);
    printf("Enter a username:\n");
    scanf("%s", saveTweet->user);
    printf("Enter the user's tweet:\n");
    scanf(" %s[^\n]", saveTweet->text);
    while (saveTweet->user[i] != '\0') {
        ascii[i] = saveTweet->user[i];
        i++;
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
        sum=sum+ascii[j];
    }
    sum=sum+strlen(saveTweet->user);
    saveTweet->id=sum;
    printf("Your generated user id is:%d\n",saveTweet->id);
    //tweetList->next=saveTweet; <-- don't insert the member into the list yet, your addNodeToList function already does it
    return (saveTweet);
}
```

also the `return` statements in your addNodeToList function are useless: the first is useless because there is the `else`, and the second because it's a void function, you don't need to specify `return` except if you want to leave the function before the end (which is not the case in your function)

Comment: This code seems to miss the important `saveTweet->next = NULL;` statement

Comment: Using `scanf`` like this is very unsafe

Comment: True, I forgot the savetweet->next my bad